# How to send a blade template to a Send Email API

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want write a RestFull API for send bulk email,
my api must get a Email template, a user or collection of users , and a attachment file as optional ,
anyone can i help me for reach a best structure for write it,Please?

2. how to pass a blade template to Email Rest API?

very thanks,
The Best Regards,

Comment: try using generic way https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#configuring-the-view

Comment: Hi Dear, very thanks, I have a email as RESTful API, I want get a template from user and pass to my API, and it send a email with it., do you know how to write it?